# Totalling values across a nested table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables, each with unique  id For example:

```html
<table id="cvo">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>O</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>V</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="prices">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="0.30" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="1.90" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="4.40" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="9.40" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="0.95" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the JS to sum up the values in the prices table based on the  value (C V or O)

So in the above example, the JS would return:
C:3.15 V:9.40 O:4.40.

I have tried the following with .find()

```
var sum = 0.0;
$('#prices > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.editbox').val();

    var amount = Number(price)

    sum+=amount;

});

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: These tables are static or you are getting these by some code.

Comment: @YograjGupta Dynamically created using an addRow function

Comment: ids should be unique and unless your tables are only a snippet, tables are for tabular data - not design purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sum = {};
var prices = $("#prices input")
$("#cvo td").each(function(index){ // for each letter
  if(!sum.hasOwnProperty($(this).text())){ // create sum of the letter if not created
    sum[$(this).text()]=0;
  }
  sum[$(this).text()]+=Number($(prices.get(index)).val()); // add the price related to the current index
})

console.log(sum)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cvo">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>O</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>V</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="prices">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="0.30" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="1.90" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="4.40" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="9.40" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="editbox " value="0.95" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. How can I then store the individual values for each C,V and O so I can append 3 input boxes?

Comment: @tomantford the individual values are stored in `sum` object, sum.C = 3.15, sum.V = 9.40, sum.O = 4.40. If you want it dynamic, you can do: `for(var letter in sum){console.log("letter "+ letter + " sum is: "+ sum[letter])}` . You can easily change the `console.log` and append input boxes

Comment: My console log returns: [Log] Object (index.php, line 443)
C : 3
O : 13
V : 5
__proto__: Object

Which is great. I've added the line: $(this).closest('tr').find('.fqty_f0').val(sum.C); but it does not seem to identify sum.C

Comment: Try doing `console.log(Object.keys(sum))` to check if the key `C` exists

Comment: the log returns [Log] ["C", "O", "V"] (index.php, line 444)

Comment: then `sum.C` should work, you can also do: `sum["C"]`. If not, then the problem is in another part of the code

Comment: I had a blank space nbsp; after the "C" that's why it wasn't picking it up! I've managed to get it working now, however if the number becomes undefined how can I return a zero? I'm using: var myInput = $('#fqty_input_f0').val('')[0];
myInput.value = sum.C.toFixed(1);

$('#fqty_f0').html (sum.C);

Comment: `if(sum.C == undefined) { sum.C = 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function GetPriceValues()
{

    var tableCvo = $('#cvo');
    var tablePrices = $('#prices');

    var trs = tableCvo.find('tr');

    var prices = {};
    $.each(trs, function(i, tr){
        var oTr = $(tr);
        var trid = oTr.attr('id');
        var text = oTr.text();
        var price = tablePrices.find('#'+trid+' .editbox').val();

        var priceObj = prices[text];
        if(!priceObj){
            prices[text] = Number(price);
        }else{
            prices[text] = prices[text]+Number(price);
        }
    });

    var keys = Object.keys(prices);
    $.each(keys, function(i, key){
        console.log(key+":"+prices[key]);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = {};

$('.editbox').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
    code = $('#' + id).text(); //ignore TD and just return text inside
    if (!sum[code]) { sum[code] = 0; }
    sum[code] += parseFloat($(this).val());
});

var result = '', i;
for (i in sum) {
    result += i + ':' + sum[i] + ' ';
}
```

You use duplicate ids in the second table, it should look like this to match to the first table:

```
<table id="prices">
    <tr data-id="1">
```

*Works only in theory, did not test, sorry.*